# Add a new parameter to the request object

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a scenario as below. I have three jsp pages jsp1, jsp2, jsp3. jsp1 calls jsp2 and jsp2 calls jsp3.

I am sending a http request from jsp1 to jsp2. I would like to add some more values to the parameters in the request object and forward that to the jsp3. Can you please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of parameters, you can add request attributes using `request.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue)`

Comment: @vinaypolisetti I can't see anythin.g

Comment: [29/09/2013 12:04:34:638] (ERROR) ajp12: Servlet Error: OracleJSP: oracle.jsp.provider.JspCompileException: &lt;H3&gt;Errors compiling:... cannot find symbol symbol  : method setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) location: interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest               request.setAttribute("USER_NAME", m_userName);

Comment: @vinaypolisetti, what IDE are you using? are the servlet jar files in your classpath? It seems like compiler is not able to find the HttpServletRequest interface.

Comment: I have used request object many times in the page but they are all not causing the issue. For example as below request.getSession(true)).putValue("ORG_ID",m_orgId); I have only one request.setAttribute("string1", "string2") which is causing the issue. Commenting this line is giving no issues